# Calculate Latitude from a Mercato Projection Map

Tags: trigonometry, image-processing

I have an Mercator Projection Map:
[image]

And I try to calculate the Latitude from a specific Y-Point on the map.
According to this article : http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/ the formula is as follow:

latitude = atan(exp(-2 * pi * y))

y = -1..1

I tried this using java code, but I do not succeed to get the expected result:

```
double southpoleLocation = 1;
double latSouthPole = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.exp(-2 * Math.PI * southpoleLocation )));
System.out.println(latSouthPole);
```

For the red circle (picture) I expected to get -90 as the latitude (degrees), but I get something near 0.

Can someone help me to get the correct latitude from a y coordination ?

Comment: Look the graph below the equation in your link, that is the equation you need to use.

Comment: Thanks , now I see. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: $latitude = \pi /2 - \tan^{-1}(\exp(-2  \pi  y))$

Comment: I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: When I use this formula for y=0 (Aquator) I get a radian of  2.35 in degrees 135. I expected to get 0. Can you help to understand what I am doing wrong. Or is the formula not correct ?

Comment: Correction:When I use this formula for y=0 (Aquator) I get a radian of  0.78 in degrees 45. I expected to get 0. Can you help to understand what I am doing wrong. Or is the formula not correct ? Why does no formula exist, which is simply correct ? Map : NorthPole Y = -1, Southpole Y = 1, Aquator Y=0. Can you please show me how you get 0 degrees for y=0 with the formula ? exp(0)=1 -> atan(1) = 0.78 in degrees = 45. So thats wrong.

Comment: I am trusting the site you shared (that is wrong when showing the formula). Anyway I missed a factor of $2$ before the inverse tangent while copying from the image.

Comment: Thanks. It now works for the extremes (-1,0,1). But If I test for Kapstadt (South Africa) it is still wrong. Kapstadt is around y = 0.2. The formula results -58 degrees, but it should be around -33 degrees. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Probably you need to "register" your map, or find another source for the formula.

Comment: What do you mean with register ? The bitmap above is a mercator map and Kapstadt is around y=0.2 . So you mean the formula is wrong ?

Comment: It seems the formula is wrong. Is there any formula out there which is correct. Also the wikipedia formula seems not to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

A likely source of confusion is that cartographers and mathematicians use different coordinate systems.  Cartographers measure latitude so that the latitude of the equator is zero degrees, whereas mathematicians measure latitude (sometimes called co-latitude) so that the latitude of the north pole is zero.

Comment: That is not the problem. Adding or subtracting 90 degrees is so obviousliy, so I would have tried that. No the problem is, that with the formulas I cant get the right latitude for CapTown for example. y=0.2 (around) and I get -58 degress insteed of -34. Between 58 and 34 is no gap of 90. So it is not the confusion you described. I would be happy to just translate the degress with 90. That would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the link you provided is incorrect. It should be
$\text{latitude} = 2\arctan\left(\exp\left(\pi y\right)\right)-\pi/2$. 
Using this I arrive at 33.8° for y=0.2

Note that since the direction of the y axis is reversed from the traditional direction, you have to multiply the result by -1, which translates to this: $\text{latitude} = \pi/2 - 2\arctan\left(\exp\left(\pi y\right)\right)$.

Also, note that the latitude of a point located at y=1 will not be -90°, but -85.05° in a Mercator projection. The poles are not represented on that projection.